# eCom "licensing issues" so removing content - good idea? Any prevention?

Tags: ip-address, geotargeting

My client has a large eCom site and due to licensing issues they can't sell in specific geographical IP ranges. They currently just remove the products so the page is basically blank.

Can anyone think of a "best practice" workaround?

Rather than zero content, perhaps we should just publish a bunch of keyword content - right?

Does any workaround come to mind? Thanks for all comments...

Comment: What would publishing a bunch of keyword content accomplish?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - something is better than nothing?

Comment: I agree that users are not well served by a blank page but what exactly is this keyword content? Why wouldn't it be able to have images in it? Was it explain the situation to the user that the product is not available in their country?